# How do I adjust the Computer Name property in vmWare Cloud Director using Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to set up a new vApp with three VM's using Terraform's vcd provider. I have a template named ubuntu-template. When I create the vApp and associated VM's using Terraform, I can see that the virtual machine name is changed to the value I specified, however the Computer Name is still set to 'ubuntu-template'. This means that the hostnames of all three VM's are 'ubuntu-template'. Is there a way to specify the Computer Name property using Terraform or by some other method?

```
resource "vcd_vapp" "ordswarmmasters" {
  name = "ordswarmmasters"
  power_on = true
}

resource "vcd_vapp_vm" "ordswarmmaster1" {
  depends_on    = ["vcd_vapp.ordswarmmasters"]
  vapp_name     = "${vcd_vapp.ordswarmmasters.name}"
  name          = "ordswarmmaster1"
  catalog_name  = "ORD"
  template_name = "ubuntu-template"
  memory        = 4096
  cpus          = 2
  cpu_cores     = 1
  power_on      = true

  network_name  = "ORD-NET"
  ip            = "dhcp"
}
```

So for the above code I have a vApp named 'ordswarmmasters' and a VM where the Virtual Machine Name is 'ordswarmmaster1', but the Computer Name in the properties remains 'ubuntu-template'.

Comment: What do you mean by computer name? Just the host name in the OS?

Comment: Within the VM properties in VCD there are two fields. One is Virtual Machine Name and the other is Computer Name. When vcd applies guest customization it will use the Computer Name value to set the hostname in the OS. So since the Computer Name value remains 'ubuntu-template' I wind up with several machines with the same hostname, forcing me to go in manually to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if you provide an initscript it will adjust the Computer Name value. I put a simple initscript in of `touch /tmp/testfile` and that was enough to get it working.